# Why does this Athena query return fewer results with a less restrictive search?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table where the column `minute` is a string.

```sql
SELECT "minute", CAST("minute" AS INTEGER), CAST("minute" AS INTEGER) = 4
FROM "db"."table"
WHERE "year" = '2023' AND "month" = '03' AND "day" = '03'
  AND "hour" = '03'
  AND "minute" = '04'
  AND CAST("minute" AS INTEGER) = 4
LIMIT 5
```

When I run this I get the expected output:

| minute | _col1 | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04 | 4 | true |
| 04 | 4 | true |
| 04 | 4 | true |
| 04 | 4 | true |
| 04 | 4 | true |

Now despite my debug columns all showing exactly what I expect, as soon as I *don't* filter on the string minutes anymore, this will get **no results**:

```sql
SELECT "minute", CAST("minute" AS INTEGER), CAST("minute" AS INTEGER) = 4
FROM "db"."table"
WHERE "year" = '2023' AND "month" = '03' AND "day" = '03'
  AND "hour" = '03'
  --AND "minute" = '04'
  AND CAST("minute" AS INTEGER) = 4
LIMIT 5
```

1. What is happening?
2. Is filtering on cast values bad?
3. How can **removing** a predicate, i.e. *relaxing* the query, lead to *fewer* results?

---

#### Update 1

This is what I get from the DDL:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table`(
  `timestamp` string COMMENT '', 
  `message` string COMMENT '')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string, 
  `day` string, 
  `hour` string, 
  `minute` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^([A-Za-z]{3} \\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} [A-Z]{3}) (.*)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://some-internal-s3-path'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'projection.day.range'='01,31', 
  'projection.day.type'='integer', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.hour.range'='00,23', 
  'projection.hour.type'='integer', 
  'projection.minute.range'='00,59', 
  'projection.minute.type'='integer', 
  'projection.month.range'='01,12', 
  'projection.month.type'='integer', 
  'projection.year.range'='2021,2030', 
  'projection.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://some-internal-s3-path/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/${minute}/', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1645569972')
```

---

#### Update 2

I discovered something that might help: The problem only occurs for single digit numbers, starting with 10 everything works as expected.

Our theory is that Athena fails to realize where it's supposed to search, given that the partitioning is based on S3 paths with one part being the minute (with single digits having a leading zero).

And the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html#partition-projection-considerations-and-limitations) talk about an issue with partitions (4th bullet point), where values outside a partition don't error but return empty.

I checked for all minute values and it really only returned 2-digit minute numbers, i.e. **"10" to "59"**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(CAST("minute" AS INTEGER))
FROM "wallet_logs_prod"."na_prod_business_logs"
WHERE "year" = '2023' AND "month" = '03' AND "day" = '03'
  AND "hour" = '03'
```

That still doesn't help me solve my problem though.

Comment: Can you provide us enough information to reproduce your situation? For example, a small sample dataset and the DDL to create the table? (Doing this might also help you narrow-in on the cause of the behaviour.)

Comment: Difficult. I don't have any experience with Athena except for the querying part. But I do understand that I can't do a simple `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: You can click the 3-dot menu beside the table name and request the DDL for the table.

Comment: I suspect that your partitions are part of the problem. Why do you partition all the way down to the minute level? It means that you have many folders and flies that are small. A more reasonable partition is to the day level or the hour if you have many events. 
The value of the minutes is taken from the folder name.

Comment: It's a humongously large “table” that's why the minute is actually needed. I'm currently running without a filter in minute (17 min and still running with scanned data in the terabytes). Also, I'm afraid the same problem is lurking for single digit hour values. That's why I'd rather solve it for real.

Answer (score 0):

Could the “minute” column contain a value for which the CAST function would result a NULL?

Try,

```
coalesce(CAST("minute" AS INTEGER), 0) = 4
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.  If it would, I should also see `NULL`s in my `_col1`, right?